# R Studio Connects Successfully to Azure SQL Database but table names are jargon

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, rstudio, rodbc

I'm attempting to connect to an Azure SQL Database server from my Mac (macOS 10.14.6) on R Studio. I'm able to successfully connect using the instructions provided here: https://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/09/18/setup-odbc-for-r-on-os-x/

However, once the connection is made the table names come back as jargon - the characters are valid - but there is clearly a severe encoding issue:

[1] "acrc_a"                       "a_lne"                        "apanrcneso"                   "askyod"
  [5] "assosrdrnsR"                  "assosrdrdcsR"                 "b"                            "cmeci_t"
  [9] "cmeiiekyod"                   "diysl"                        "diyslsPO"                     "dt_nert"
 [13] "dfcwr"                        "frcs_mn"                      "frcs_io"                      "frcs_A"
 [17] "frcs_A_ak"                    "frcs_nio_A"                   "fidla"                        "fifrcs_cua"
 [21] "fiupv"                        "gac_i"                        "gol_rn"                       "ivnoyhat"
 [25] "ieNre"                        "keapii"                       "kyodbd"                       "kyodbd_itrc"
 [29] "mse_potnt"                    "ntp"                          "nwkyod"                       "pe_oeatcagl"

I have no idea what the issue could possibly be. I'm using freetds for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server. I am also able to connect and query using isql on the terminal without an encoding issue.

```
conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "MSSQL", 
    Server = "franklinsportsdw.database.windows.net", Database = "FranklinSportsDB", 
    Port = 1433)
```

(Username and password removed)

Any help anyone out there can bring would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FreeTDS, use the free, supported Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server.  See [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks David. I have both installed and working on my terminal (ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server). Exact same issue.

Comment: Can you add enough code to your question to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'd need to give you the password to my db unfortunately - only way to connect and see the problem.